# Download embedded videos in html using c++

Tags: javascript, c++, html, caching, video-streaming

I'm developing a caching application with c++ under linux. I managed to make it run perfectly for static contents found in pages html source. however it can't cache contents generated dynamically with Javascript and flash like Youtube videos

My question is:

- is it possible to download such contents from my application (by executing js and running from my c++ app for e.g) ?
- is there a know solution that work in most cases ?
- How do Firefox plug-ins do it ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Yes there are known solutions. Plugins leverage API's provided by the browser. One option is to write it all yourself. Another option is to use something like Webkit.

Comment: a link or document please where i can start from ? my application is console application, can i use a webkit in it (I thought about using mozilla gecko, but will it run flash directly ? what i need to do with ? write a plug in for it ? it's not very clear) ? I really appreciate your comment and further explanation :)